# Inside of my Linux server I can't ping out to IPv6 URLs

Tags: ipv6

Inside of my Linux server I can't ping out to IPv6 URLS.

Pinging IPv4 works as expected.

For example:

```
$ ping6 google.com
```

I get one line of output and then it sits indefinitely,

```
PING google.com(ord30s26-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4009:80f::200e)) 56 data bytes
```

I turned off my firewall and SELinux and that didn't fix it.

The server does have an IPv6 address assigned to an interface and IPv6 is enabled.

```
$ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe99::99b:99ff:fe99:d99e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

In my control panel Outbound rules are open.

> Type: All traffic
>
> Protocol: All
>
> Port Range: All
>
> Destination: ::/0

Comment: You do not have global IPv6 connectivity. Contact your ISP.

Comment: Perhaps I am revealing a huge knowledge gap, but I wonder if an IPv6 address that starts with FE99 is legitimate. In any case, the scope is *link*, which means that you can only reach addresses in your network. To reach Google, you need a *global* scope.

Comment: Actually FE99 matches the link-local definition of fe80::/10. This means that this address is a legitimate link-local address, but you can reach the internet with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.  IPv6 was not set up properly during install.

I solved the problem by logging into the root user and editing my config file.

```
# cat <<EOF >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
EOF
```

After reboot IPv6 worked perfect.